# Is commutativity of the ring $R$ essential in the above result? Justify.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $N$ be the set of all nilpotent elements of $R.$ Show that $N$ forms an ideal of $R$ and the quotient ring $R/N$ has no non-zero
nilpotent elements. Is commutativity of the ring $R$ essential in the above result? Justify.

My solution is as follows:

If $R$ is a commutative ring and $N$ is the set of all nilpotent elements of $R$ then, $N=\{a\in R:a^n=0,$ for some integer $n\in\Bbb Z^+\}.$

Let $x,y\in N$ then, $\exists n_1,n_2\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $x^{n_1}=y^{n_2}=0.$

Now, $(x+y)^{n_1+n_2}=x^{n_1+n_2}+\binom{n_1+n_2}{1}x^{n_1+n_2-1}y+\cdots +\binom{n_1+n_2}{n_1+n_2}y^{n_1+n_2}=0.$

This means, $x+y\in N.$

Again, $(-x)^{n_1}=(-1)^{n_1}x^{n_1}=0.$ This means, $-x\in N.$

So, $N$ is a subgroup of $R$ under addition.

Let $r\in R$ then, $rx,xr\in N$ as $(rx)^{n_1}=0=(xr)^{n_1}.$ So, $N$ is an ideal.

Now, we claim that, $R/N$ has no non zero nilpotent element. This is because, say, $w\in R/N$ is a nilpotent element in $R/N$. Now, $\exists r\in R$ such that $r+N=w.$ This means, $\exists n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $w^n=N=r^n+N.$ This means $r^n\in N.$ Now, this implies $r^{nk}=0,$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z^+.$ Hence, $r\in N$ as well. So, $w=r+N=N.$

But, $w$ is any arbitrary nilpotent element of $R/N$ and hence, $N$ is the only nilpotent element in $R/N.$ Thus, $R/N$ has no non-zero nilpotent element.

---

However, I feel that commutativity of the ring $R$ essential in the above result but I am unable to justify this claim. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Calculate $(x + y)^2$ in a non-commutative ring. (The answer should be equal to $(y + x)^2$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binomial theorem requires commutativity. And indeed we see that this part of the proof can fail in non-commutative rings, such as for instance the ring of $2\times 2$ integer matrices, where
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not nilpotent. So $N$ is not closed under addition, and can therefore not be an ideal (neither right, left, nor two-sided).